# Unique state in multiple instances of same component

Tags: nuxtjs3

Is there a way to make `useState` **not** to share the state between multiple instances of the same component without hacking the `key` argument with `Math.random()`.

```
const activated = useState("activated", () => false)
```

Comment: `const activated = ref(false)`?

Comment: Is there any general guidline when to use ref and when to use useState?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest to use `useState` if you want to share state. If you don't want to, you could use `const activated = ref(false)`. You must not use it outside the `setup` function though.

`const activated = () => useState(false)` would be another option (see https://v3.nuxtjs.org/guide/features/state-management).